# How do I use Toast notification properly on android?

Tags: android, notifications, toast, android-context

I can't seem to be able to use the toast notification properly. In all of my other apps it worked great but in this one it doesn't. In this app I started using openGL with a framework from a book named "Beginning Android Games" and now I don't seem to be able to use the toast notification.  I have no idea what to do... It fails because of the context. How can I make a context that will work? Please help me! this is part of my code because the code is too long:

```
private void updateReady() {
Coin.number = 0;
if (game.getInput().getTouchEvents().size() > 0) {
    state = GAME_RUNNING;
    Coin.number = 0;
    Num.number = 0;

    Toast.makeText(this, "Start!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When I put the line:

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "Start!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

in the class that extends Activity and run it it just doesn't do anything... I tried to make it into a method and call it from other classes but it got a force close...

Comment: Where is this snippet located? whcih class?

Comment: In the class that the main class extends i think

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `getApplicationContext()` to get a reference to the current `Activity` context

Comment: when i type it, it gives me an error sating "The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type GameScreen". probably because I am not extending Activity. I am extending GLScreen, if you worked with this framework before you might know what i'm talking about. Anyways.. how can i extend both ?

Comment: @Baruch, try `getApplication()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make your application context, or the context of whatever activity you're starting your `GameScreen` from, available statically or by passing it as an argument from whatever creates your instance.

Having said that, though, [beware of memory leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)!

Comment: But none of them extends Activity.. is it still possible?

Comment: Well, surely somewhere along your chain (following it back from your code above to where the app is launched) you must have an activity, right? So just pass the context along to the class that needs it... Edit: Or, like I said, make it available statically... see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android) as well.

Comment: I looked at the question but didn't really understand the answer... Can you please write for me the right code? Btw i tried some of the answers but i got a force close...

Comment: I can't write a solution for you without knowing your code... are you sure you had a look at what I said and tried to follow the chain back from where your game screen gets initialised to where you've got ahold of an activity (possibly your main activity)? You can just put a break point in your code and "Debug As... -> Android App" and see what calls what if you don't remember. That should give you an idea of how to get a handle on an activity.

Comment: You're not making it easy for the people who are trying to help if you don't give us better information on what is going wrong. Perhaps you should consider starting with some easier tutorials, e.g. [vogella](http://www.vogella.de/android.html), rather than jumping into game development? I'm getting no indication that you're listening to or trying out what I've said. Good luck finding what you're after.

Comment: The main thing that goes wrong is the context. I checked in the logcat and it says that when it calls the toast it has problem with the context. everything else is alright. I am sorry if it is hard to understand me. English is my second language and I am not an expert in android.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps.

I had class defined like this

```
    public class tutorialThree extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
```

I tried to use Toast like this

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Did not work, because my class implements that interface "View.OnClickListener" (or whatever it is :))
So toast gets confused with "this" reference, you have to be more precise, so add name of your class before "this" keyword, like this:

```
    Toast.makeText(tutorialThree.this, "Wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This solved my problem, now i can see toast.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're working with this framework called "[Beginning Android Games 2](https://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games-2/)".

According to this [code](https://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games-2/source/browse/trunk/ch11-gl-advanced/src/com/badlogic/androidgames/framework/impl/GLScreen.java), the instance variable you need here is `glGame`, which is a [GLGame](https://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games-2/source/browse/trunk/ch11-gl-advanced/src/com/badlogic/androidgames/framework/impl/GLGame.java) object. It extends [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), so you can just do this:

```
Toast.makeText(glGame, "Start!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```